# onLocationChanged call the onDraw method in my custom view

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, draw

I have a MapImageViewer Activity class that has methods for checking the phones gps location. This activity then calls a custom view of mine called MapCanvas - where the constructor takes the latitude and longitude and then draws a circle to the corresponding pixels on an image of a map.

This works ok, but I am wondering how can I update and call the onDraw method every time the gps coordinates change? I know it needs to go in the onLocationChanged method..but i'm not sure how i can pass the new latitude and longitude values from there to my Custom View class.

Answer (score 0):

Call the view's `invalidate()` method every time you get new coordinates (or `postInvalidate()` if the locationListener is in a different thread from the UI thread)

Comment: I don't see how calling the views invalidate (or postInvalidate) method will do anything.

Comment: It tells the operating system to redraw the view thus calling the view's onDraw() method as well as any other behind-the-scenes preparation the operating system must do.  invalidate is how you force draw a view.

Comment: I tried putting this in my onLocationChanged method and it didn't work..  mapCanvas = new MapCanvas(MapImageViewer.this, myMapImagePath, latitude, longitude); 
setContentView(mapCanvas);
mapCanvas.invalidate();

Comment: scratch that..i mean..I tried putting this in my onLocationChanged method and it didn't work..  mapCanvas.setLat(latitude);  //new lat value mapCanvas.setLon(longitude); //new longitude value
mapCanvas.invalidate();   //redraw view

Comment: invalidate is how you get onDraw() called on a view.  Assuming MapCanvas extends MapView, it seems like that would work.  I've only added overlays to MapViews though.  I've never actually drawn anything directly.  I would send a message to LogCat in the onDraw() method to ensure it's getting called.  If it is, then ensure the map is being drawn properly.

Comment: MapCanvas extends View because it is my custom view. Inside that class is a constructor (context, imagePath, lat, lon) and an onDraw() method. I'm using a custom map image and not google maps.

Comment: it works now. It must have been some dodgy gps readings the first time I tried it

Answer (score 0):

What about sending lat/lon from the `onLocationChanged()` method by using `.sendBroadcast()` and handle them inside your View class with a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Alternatively you could use a callback method from the LocationListener like shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an) post.

Comment: isn't the sendBroadcast() and receiveBroadcast() used when creating intents? In my case I am setting my content view to my Custom View..and in the Custom View class I need to pass in the new long/lat values..and call onDraw on every change..